# Powershell Stored Procedure with Parameters

Tags: sql, powershell

How would I add parameters to this stored procedure? And am I doing anything else wrong? I've already established my connection to server/db. I've searched, but keep getting conflicting answers. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_name_here"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $srcCnn

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply call the Add method on the command object's Parameters property.

```
$Param = $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@paramName", [Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar)
$Param.Direction = [Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
$Param.Value = "SomeValueHere"
```