# Prevent variable and special character substitution in variable

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I'm loading a regex from a file into a database using a stored procedure, like this:

```
$stuff = Get-Content -Path '.\data.txt' -Raw
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Exec dbo.loadStuff @stuff='$stuff'" -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Username $username -Password $password
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes the file contains `$randomtext` which PowerShell then fails to expand because the `$randomtext` variable doesn't exist.

Is there a way to tell PowerShell to pass the contents of the `$stuff` variable as is without expanding it?

Adding `-DisableVariables` doesn't appear to work.

EDIT: As zett42 pointed out, PowerShell isn't performing a second expansion. It is passing the full text to `sqlcmd`.

`sqlcmd` is finding `$(randomtext)` and treating it as a variable. `-DisableVariables` should have fixed this, but it hasn't.

After removing all $ signs from the test source file it is still failing, and I suspect that it is due to `$stuff` containing single and double quotes.

I hadn't realised that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is simply a pass through to `sqlcmd`. I will stop using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` and follow the resource provided by zett42 instead.

Comment: Variables encapsulated within single quotes aren't expanded. For example, `Write-Host '$home'` would literally print `$home`, not the contents of the variable.

Comment: Yes. But, I don't want the word `$stuff` to be passed to the stored procedure. I want the contents of the `$stuff` variable, but not expanded any further.

Comment: PowerShell expands strings only once, so `$randomtext` contained in `data.txt` will be passed literally to SQL query, which means this is an issue of SQL only. You should pass `$stuff` as actual SQL parameter instead of literal string. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35469287/7571258).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` is great for simple calls, but if you're going to do anything more complex (like pass arbitrary text as a parameter) it's best to use the .NET stack like `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`.

I have rewritten my code to use this more appropriate approach and I am able to pass bound parameters (no possibility of SQL injection) **without either PowerShell or sqlcmd mangling or trying to parse the parameter values** (both of which were the cause of the original problems).